# Thermal conductivity and diffusivity of diatomite (also known as diatomaceous earth or kieselguhr)

Tags: temperature, thermal

Cross-posted [on Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/25763/18946) and [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/177860/27342).

Does anyone know where can I find measured thermal conductivity and thermal diffusivity of diatomite for different temperatures? I'm looking for the temperature dependency for temperatures higher than 300K. The upper temperature limit shall be at least 1000K, but more is better. All I have found is thermal conductivity in "Touloukian, Y. S., et al. "Thermophysical properties of matter - The TPRC data series. Volume 2. Thermal conductivity - nonmetallic solids. (1971)". I'm still missing data on thermal diffusivity though, and I'd like to see more data on thermal conductivity, if available.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question has been asked (and answered) on several sites